# javascript precedence. var1 = var2 < 100;

Tags: javascript, equation

I have just come across the javascript code

`file_upload_started = progress < 100;`

and I have NO idea how to read it and Google isn't really turning much up. I'm not even sure what to call it so it's hard to do a search.

If anyone has any information about this type of equation, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: what you are looking for is called operator precedence

Comment: Be careful with the word "equation".  This is not an assertion of equality, it's just an assignment.  You might want to keep the word equation unsullied, for real math stuff.

Comment: Thanks James, I changed the wording a bit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It stores the result of the expression `progress < 100` (*a boolean result*) to the variable `file_upload_started`

So if `progress` is less than `100` then it will set the `file_upload_started` to `true`, otherwise to `false`

Answer (score 2):

It's setting `file_upload_started` to the boolean result of `progress < 100`

So if `progress` is 99, `file_upload_started` will be `true`, and of course if progress is 100 or greater, then `file_upload_started` will be false;

Not to belabor the point, but you could write that same code as:

```
if (progress < 100)
    file_upload_started = true;
else
    file_upload_started = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

Standard javascript. The expression on the right hand side is evaluated and the result assigned to the left hand side, so:

```
progress < 100
```

is evaluated and will return either true or false (or an error if progress hasn't been defined). That result is assigned:

```
file_upload_started = <value of expression>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Read it something like this:

```
file_upload_started = (progress < 100);
```

It just returns a boolean value that is set to the variable.